# xCode 5.1 doesn't recognize a class in the file system "relative to folder" (real folder)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, directory

I am using xCode 5.1, but when I try to include a folder that contains two files (.m and  .h) as "folder reference" in place of "group",

[image: folder reference]

I have to include the path folder in the "Build settings --> Header search paths" else xcode says "files not found".
The problem is that when I include the folder's path I found another error "Undefined symbols for architecture XXX", but the problem can't be the architecture. I think the problem is that the project hasn't access to the .m file inside the folder referenced.

I have tried also to drag the .m file to ‘Build phases—>Compile Sources’ and… xCode crash, always. I do 'clean build folder' but the result is the same.

If, instead of including the entered folder in the project navigator, I drag the files, there is not problem, but, when i insert new files in the folder, they don't appear in my project navigator.  Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem since I updated to 5.1 on March 11. I noticed that Library Search Path and the Header search path are updated but the paths are not surrounded by "". In my case, because I had a path with spaces in it, it was splitting each entry at the space and making it two entries. I had to manually edit the search paths to include the ""